# Resharper: enum suggestions not fired automatically

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

VS2008 has nice enum suggestions eg if you press space after "=" and enum value is expected it automatically suggest all enums.

Noticed it gone after installing R#

Do you know how make it working back ??? Lack of this is really pain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug that has been [reported here](http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP-61100). If you'd like to encourage JetBrains to fix it, sign up on their Jira site and vote/watch/comment on the bug.

There is no workaround apart from not using Resharper at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to disable the R#'s IntelliSense (and use VS buit-in IntelliSence instead).

In Visual Studion, goto ReSharper (menu) -> Option -> IntelliSense -> General -> Visual Studio

I'm using R# 6